# Trying to get property of non-object Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have this route which is in an authorised group:

```
Route::get('clan/leave',[
        'as' => 'clan-leave',
        'uses' => 'ClanController@getLeave'
    ]);
```

This leads to my ClanController with the function getLeave() which this is:

```
public function getLeave(){
    return "Test";
}
```

I then have a basic link which takes the user to /clan/leave which should kick in the controllers function and display "Test". This is not happening, I am getting this error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object: Laravel\app\views\clan\display.blade.php
```

I do not see why this display file is even getting involved. I do have another route /clan which routes to this.

What am I not seeing?
Many thanks.

Comment: So what is in display.blade.php? Can you provide the content of that file relevant to your question?

Comment: I'm currently not at my PC. I am able to get the contents later though. I believe it isn't the issue with the contents of that file, as it shouldn't even be using that file. The routing shouldn't be taking it there. That file uses objects to display info so I can see why it has errors when trying to go to that file without the objects being provided. Regardless, it shouldn't be going to that file. Right?

Comment: How do you generate the URL. Your _as_ uses - not . is this intentional?

Comment: The routes name is clan-leave. The url is generated with URL::route('clan-leave'). Sorry, what do you mean by uses not?

Comment: I was just point out the fact that you were using a dash and not a dot in your route name, and whether it was intentional. I don't really get why this isn't working, I can not find anything wrong with the code and examples you have provided. You say that it shouldn't be using the _display.blade.php_ file, yet this file is referenced in the exception message. You need to backtrace with the help of the debug message to find out where this originates.

Comment: Oh I see. The dash is intentional. How would I be able to backtrace? I'm not used to debugging Laravel.

Comment: Enable debug for your testing environment, if it is not enabled already, and try following the steps backwards. Use dd(variable) to die and dump, this can be useful when debugging. To get more help here you need to include more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my problem.

I have this route:

```
Route::get('clan/{id}',[
        'as' => 'clan',
        'uses' => 'ClanController@getOther'
    ]);
```

And this route was being fired rather than the intended one. I can only assume this is fired off because it was picking up clan/leave (leave as a variable, rather than a route). I have fixed this by moving this route to the bottom of my routes

Comment: Routes are done from top to bottom in Laravel, with the first matching being the first chosen. The best thing to do is place wildcard / parameter ones last, or lower on the pile.